# Is there an Apple Silicon status dashboard for common development tools?

Tags: apple-silicon

There are numerous questions here already about whether (and when or if) many specific tools will run on Apple Silicon but I can find no resource (yet) that tracks the status of common developer tools and toolchains.

Is there a dashboard or website that tracks Apple Silicon compatibility for common or widely used tools and utilities (e.g. Homebrew and commonly used packages or packages with wide dependencies, the top dozen or so coding languages and tool stacks, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a dashboard but you can take a look at https://doesitarm.com/